# How would I block a computer's access to certain domains from within an iOS cocoa app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, dns, block

Basically I am trying to make a button inside an iOS app I'm making block access to a certain domain while the app is running.

I've been programming for a couple of years but am new to iOS app dev and am not sure how to go about this.

Cheers for any help!

Comment: You want to prevent other apps from accessing a domains while your app is running? That wouldn't be possible since iOS apps run inside their own sandbox

Comment: Are you sure it's not possible? I know there is an mac app called SelfControl which blocks domains for a certain amount of time

Comment: macOS != iOS ;-) Mac-Apps can have far more access to the system than iOS-Apps

Comment: oh ahahaha of course sorry dude, would you happen to know about macOS at all??